# Intro.js - show only one step

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intro.js

I'm currently working with Intro.js or actually angular-intro.js.

What I'm trying now is that you can take a complete tour, but also be able to only show one step (and having no chance to look for another step).

I know that I can start at a specific step using `CallMe(3)` to start from step 3, and I know that I can disable the navigation buttons, setting `showButtons` to false. But is there any way to have both, so a button with `CallMe()` behind, thats showing the complete tour and a button with `CallMe(3)` or a selfwritten function, that only shows the step given?

This is how I call the tour:

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success" ng-click="$ctrl.CallMe();">Demo</button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" ng-click="$ctrl.CallMe(3);">Start at step 3</button>
```

And this how the tour is defined:

```
this.IntroOptions = {
            steps: [
                {
                    element: document.querySelector('#step1'),
                    intro: "This is the first tooltip."
                },
                {
                    element: document.querySelectorAll('#step2')[0],
                    intro: "<strong>You</strong> can also <em>include</em> HTML",
                    position: 'right'
                },
                {
                    element: '.nicediv',
                    intro: 'More features, more fun.'
                },
                {
                    element: '#step4',
                    intro: "Another step.",
                    position: 'bottom'
                },
                {
                    element: '#step5',
                    intro: 'Get it, use it.'
                },
                {
                    element: '#tollesP',
                    intro: 'Scrolling of course works as well.'
                }
            ],
            showStepNumbers: false,
            showBullets: false,
            exitOnOverlayClick: true,
            exitOnEsc: true,
            nextLabel: '<strong>NEXT!</strong>',
            prevLabel: '<span style="color:green">Previous</span>',
            skipLabel: 'Exit',
            doneLabel: 'Thanks',
            showProgress: true,
            showButtons: true
        };
```

Comment: and there is a way to have some code posted?

Comment: added some code, if it helps you...

Comment: Why not use two functions? Have `callMe1()` which gives full tour with buttons, and `callMe2()` which has `showButtons` off. Then each buttons calls a different function that behaves how you want.